# How can I improve the performance of the following code?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

This code is working but taking too much time. Every data table contains 1000nds of rows and each time I need to filter data from another data tables with respect to a column.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataTable dtFiltered = dtWorkExp.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow drr in dtWorkExp.Rows)
    {
        if (drr["UserId"].ToString() == dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Registration NO."].ToString())
        {
            dtFiltered.ImportRow(drr);
        }
    }

    DataTable dtFilteredAward= dtAwards.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow drr in dtAwards.Rows)
    {
        if (drr["UserId"].ToString() == dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Registration NO."].ToString())
        {
            dtFilteredAward.ImportRow(drr);
        }
    }

    DataTable dtFilteredOtherQual = dtOtherQual.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow drr in dtOtherQual.Rows)
    {
        if (drr["UserId"].ToString() == dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Registration NO."].ToString())
        {
            dtFilteredOtherQual.ImportRow(drr);
        }
    }

    //Do some operation with filtered Data Tables
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [filtered `DataView`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/filtering-with-dataview-linq-to-dataset) instead of copying data from table to table?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare these lines outside the for loop.

```
  DataTable dtFiltered = dtWorkExp.Clone();
```

And instead of doing accessing dsResult.Table[0] each time, you can assign this to one variable and use it.

You can also replace the foreach loop with LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Put the value of the expression in a variable.

```
var regNo = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Registration NO."].ToString();
```

Put the index of column to the variable. Access by index more faster then by column name.

```
int index = dtWorkExp.Columns["UserId"].Ordinal;
```

Result code:

```
int dtWorkIndex = dtWorkExp.Columns["UserId"].Ordinal;
int dtAwardsIndex = dtAwards.Columns["UserId"].Ordinal;
int dtOtherQualIdex = dtOtherQual.Columns["UserId"].Ordinal;

for (int i = 0; i < dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var regNo = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Registration NO."].ToString();

    DataTable dtFiltered = dtWorkExp.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow drr in dtWorkExp.Rows)
    {
        if (drr[dtWorkIndex].ToString() == regNo)
        {
            dtFiltered.ImportRow(drr);
        }
    }
    ...
```

Of course, the column index can be set as a constant if you know it exactly in advance. Also, if the UserId indexes match in all tables, a single variable is sufficient.

---

You can also try using the [BeginLoadData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.beginloaddata) and [EndLoadData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.endloaddata) methods.

```
DataTable dtFiltered = dtWorkExp.Clone();
dtFiltered.BeginLoadData();

foreach (DataRow drr in dtWorkExp.Rows)
{
    if (drr[dtWorkIndex].ToString() == regNo)
    {
        dtFiltered.ImportRow(drr);
    }
}
dtFiltered.EndLoadData();
```

But I'm not sure if they make sense together with `ImportRow`.

---

Finally, parallelization comes to help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var regNo = ...;

    var workTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DataTable dtFiltered = dtWorkExp.Clone();
    
        foreach (DataRow drr in dtWorkExp.Rows)
        {
            if (drr[dtWorkIndex].ToString() == regNo)
            {
                dtFiltered.ImportRow(drr);
            }
        }
        return dtFiltered;
    });
    
    var awardTask = Task.Run(() =>
        ...
    
    var otherQualTask = Task.Run(() =>
        ...
    
    //Task.WaitAll(workTask, awardTask, otherQualTask);
    await Task.WhenAll(workTask, awardTask, otherQualTask);
    
    //Do some operation with filtered Data Tables
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

All rows of the main datatable as enumerable:

```
var rows = dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
```

Get the column you're going to filter with:

```
var filter = rows.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Registration NO."));
```

Create a method that accepts that filter, a table to filter and a field to compare.

```
public static DataTable Filter<T>(EnumerableRowCollection<T> filter, DataTable table, string fieldName)
{
    return table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => filter.Contains(r.Field<T>(fieldName))).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Finally use the method to filter all tables:

```
var dtFiltered = Filter<string>(filter, dtWorkExp, "UserId");
var dtFilteredAward = Filter<string>(filter, dtAwards, "UserId");
var dtFilteredOtherQual = Filter<string>(filter, dtOtherQual, "UserId");
```

All together woul be something like this

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    var rows = dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
    var filter = rows.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Registration NO."));
    var dtFiltered = Filter<string>(filter, dtWorkExp, "UserId");
    var dtFilteredAward = Filter<string>(filter, dtAwards, "UserId");
    var dtFilteredOtherQual = Filter<string>(filter, dtOtherQual, "UserId");
}

public static DataTable Filter<T>(EnumerableRowCollection<T> filter, DataTable table, string fieldName)
{
    return table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => filter.Contains(r.Field<T>(fieldName))).CopyToDataTable();
}
```